# Is the CMB present in an artificial shielded vacuum?

Tags: cosmology, cosmic-microwave-background, cosmic-rays

I see the wiki page of [cosmic microwave background (CMB)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_microwave_background) radiation says it is "present in all space"; I wonder, if I build a vacuum box with sufficient shielding, say a box with thick metal walls, and cool the walls to near 0K, can I still detect the CMB in this box?  Are there direct experimental measurements for this setup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CMB is just electromagnetic radiation and behaves like any other electromagnetic radiation. Specifically it can be shielded using a Faraday cage just like any other EM radiation.

The only problem is that (as you allude to in your question) if the Faraday cage is warmer than the 2.7K temperature of the CMB it will emit black body radiation at similar or greater levels than the CMB. However if you cool your Faraday cage to near absolute zero then yes inside the cage there will be no CMB radiation.

I don't know of any experiment to test whether the CMB can be screened. I'd be surprised if anyone thought it was worth doing.

Comment: Got it; it is a leftover of the recombination event, rather than an intrinsic property of the space.  Its redshift is, however, caused by the expansion of the space itself.  Would be interesting if experiments prove otherwise; though I think it very unlikely personally.

Comment: It should be said there is no real Faraday cage known that could completely block X-ray/gamma radiation. CMB radiation should have a weak X-ray/gamma component, so that part of CMB can't be easily blocked by a Faraday cage.

Answer (score 0):

No, you could not detect the CMB in such a box. Yes, the fact that dilution refrigerators routinely achieve millikelvin temperatures in their cryovolumes proves that the 2.7K thermal background radiation is shielded with a bit of cold metal.